# Magento CheckOut js validation error

Tags: javascript, validation, magento, checkout

I started to edit a magento template and I stumbled upon an error: if I miss a required field and click the submit button, the "this is a required field" text appears underneath the respective field; but when I recomplete the form and click the 'submit" button for the second time, I realise that it is blocked.

Has anyone gone through the same thing? I don't know javascript at all and I'm not able to do it myself.

Im in a great need of getting this done, so please, lend me a hand.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else who finds this question: I ran into this issue and after much debugging realised that it was because I had removed `scriptaculous/effects.js` from the layout of the checkout page.

The form validation JS depends on `effects.js`, but the code that uses it is inside a `try/catch` block meaning that you will not get console errors, and instead the form will just fail to revalidate correctly.

Comment: This is the answer. I have also been experiencing this validation error in checkout. Upon reading this answer, I remembered that I, too, had removed `effects.js` from `layout/page.xml` template. Adding that script back into the file did indeed fix the validation issue..

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this link it will give an explanation of the javascript validation in Magento. the thing to look for is the `class` in the `text/select fields`  if it has `required` or any of the other ones listed in the link, it will run the validation through those.

http://fishpig.co.uk/magento-tutorials/magento-forms-prototype-javascript-validation

Comment: Yes,the inputs seem to have validation classes assigned,the problem is that after the validation is triggered and throws out "This field is required" text,the process cannot continue because the submit button is dead.
In other words,if validation is triggered i must refresh the page and start all over again without making any mistakes,and this isnt too userfriendly and the validation has no meaning in that case.